# I'm confused on which comparison operators to use for my JavaScript game. I have tried using the options &&, and ||

Tags: javascript, html

The problem : When the User types in something in the textbox such as 2 (paper) or 3 (scissors) the "ComputerChoice" will randomly generate a number 1 through 3. What I am trying to do is have the computer understand the scenarios such as ...

*For Example ... code below*

```
If (UserChoice == 1 || ComputerCoice == 3)
{
 // execute a win message 
}
```

But I believe that the first scenarios (If the user chooses rock [aka "1"]) is throwing the whole system off. I'm using this many If-statements because we have not learned cases or nested-Ifs yet. If you need any clarification please feel free to comment down below.

#### Here's my JavaScript code ...

```
function Game() {

 var rock = 1;
 var paper = 2;
 var scissors = 3;

var ComputerChoice = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3 + 1);
var UserChoice = document.getElementById("user").value;

console.log(ComputerChoice); // to check validity

if (UserChoice == 1 | ComputerChoice == 1) { // The rock portion of the game is 100% functional
  document.getElementById("user").innerHTML = "<h2>Hmm, we have a tie! I chose </h2>" + ComputerChoice + " <h2>too.</h2>";
} 

else if (UserChoice == 1 | ComputerChoice == 2) {
  document.getElementById("user").innerHTML = "<h2>You lost! The computer chose</h2>" + ComputerChoice;
} 

else if (UserChoice = 1 | ComputerChoice == 3) {
  document.getElementById("user").innerHTML = "<h2>You won! The computer chose</h2>" + ComputerChoice;
}

  else if (ComputerChoice == 2 | UserChoice == 2) { // says i lose
  document.getElementById("user").innerHTML = "<h2>Hmm, we have a tie! I chose </h2>" + ComputerChoice + " <h2>too.</h2>";
} 

else if (UserChoice == 2 | ComputerChoice == 3) { // says I win??
  document.getElementById("user").innerHTML = "<h2>You lost! The computer chose</h2>" + ComputerChoice;
} 

else if (UserChoice == 2 | ComputerChoice == 1) { // says i tie
  document.getElementById("user").innerHTML = "<h2>You won! The computer chose</h2>" + ComputerChoice;
} 

   else if (UserChoice == 3 | ComputerChoice == 3) { // says i win??
  document.getElementById("user").innerHTML = "<h2>Hmm, we have a tie! I chose </h2>" + ComputerChoice + " <h2>too.</h2>";
} 

 else if (ComputerChoice == 3 | UserChoice == 1) { // scissors also tie?
  document.getElementById("user").innerHTML = "<h2>You lost! The computer chose</h2>" + ComputerChoice;
} 

 else if (UserChoice == 3 | ComputerChoice == 2) { // says i lose??
  document.getElementById("user").innerHTML = "<h2>You won! The computer chose</h2>" + ComputerChoice;
}
```

}

HTML

```
 <html>
    <body>

  <center>
       <div style="width:793px; height:62px ;border:6px; background-color:#263035"><h1>Rock= 1 Paper= 2 Scissors= 3</h1></div>
    </center>


 <center>
    <img src="https://developer.ibm.com/dwblog/wp-content/uploads/sites/73/2016/02/dwblog-rockpaperscissors-e1455070810415.png" width="850" height="425" alt= "Rock, Paper, or Scissors">

    <br>

  <input type="text" placeholder="Make your choice...">

    <br>

    <button id="user" onclick="Game();"> Good Luck! </button>

     </center>

   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Logical OR in javascript is double pipes: ||.  Your code uses a single pipe: |.  You probably want to use the AND operator though for this scenario: &&.

Comment: else if (UserChoice == 2 && ComputerChoice == 1) { // says i tie
      document.getElementById("user").innerHTML = "<h2>You won! The computer chose</h2>" + ComputerChoice;
   } After i made the change,  document.getElementById("user").innerHTML doesn't execute. So it does not show the outcome of the decision .

Comment: Don't add code to the comment section, It is completely barely readable. Edit your question using the _edit_ link at the bottom of your question.

Comment: How are you getting the input, do you have an HTML? If you have a button you should have a click event function that processes the result. I'd be helpful if you add you HTML to the question

Comment: @Marcs I apologize and understand. I am currently adding my HTML code

Comment: @nottu I added my HTML. See what i mean, i have an onclick tag with the button but nothing occurs.

Comment: You should read the value from the input, currently you're reading the button. just add an id to the input field and use that for UserChoise

Comment: @nottu <input type="text" id="user" placeholder="Make your choice..."> here is my <input> and here is my button after the change                 <button onclick="Game();"> Good Luck! </button>

Comment: I've edited my question with a fiddle link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd have to use the `&&` it's an 'and' operator. So when the `if block` gets executed you check both conditions, otherwise only one of them has to be true.

here's a JSFiddle with a working version

https://jsfiddle.net/y9uohpzq/

Note, the code is quite messy and it can be done with way less `if else blocks`

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but when I have attempted this I never recieved any output from the document.getElementById("user").innerHTML. I even used the same code, all i did was change the symbols.